# How to connect Azure Api Management to micro services orchestrated by AKS

Tags: azure, containers, microservices, azure-api-management

I have followed instructions in https://fizzylogic.nl/2017/06/16/how-to-connect-azure-api-management-to-your-kubernetes-cluster/ and managed to get connection from the API Management to micro service running in Kubernetes cluster. However, the instructions cover connection ONLY TO A SPECIFIC NODE. In real world there will be multiple nodes and perhaps even auto scaling so that the nodes come and go. So, isn't it possible to connect the API management to the Kubernetes service instead?

Or how should I work if I wanted to use AKS to orchestrate microservices and Azure API Manager to publish API's out from them?

Answer (score 0):

So far API Management has no specific support for Kubernetes. But it does support calling any HTTP endpoint, so if there is a single HTTP endpoint with proxy/load-balancer that takes nodes and scaling into account before choosing to which node to forward request that would work fine. So despite that this article suggests using NodePort service, I'd give it a shot with LoadBalancer or ExternalName. Those should provide you with a stable endpoint to call and will handle all node specific routing tasks for you.